# How to switch google app engine account to deploy applications?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have 2 google app engine accounts.  one is personal account. another one is work account.

to deploy apps to google app engine.  first time, I am using "goapp deploy", it asked me for email and password. now I got stuck with it. I cannot switch to another account.

i tried to reboot my mac, it does not work. what should i do to deploy using another account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the *--email* option in the command line, like explained  in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp)

Comment: i just tried that, managed to get it working with both --email and --no_cookies

Comment: They probably have changed the documentation. There is no mention of `--email` in the link in your answer