# How do I change what account I use for deployment to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Im having a problem where I used one account to deploy to GAE through terminal and GAE SDK, i.e goapp deploy. Not at a later point I need to deploy to another account but I dont understand how to change this in terminal? How do I trigger a new login to happen?

I read this question: [How to switch google app engine account to deploy applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049181/how-to-switch-google-app-engine-account-to-deploy-applications) but I dont get it to work either. I write the `--email=bla@gmail.com` flag but get the error message:

```
flag provided but not defined: -email
```

Am I using the `--email` flag wrong or maybe wrong parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the --no_cookies flag, e.g.:

```
python2.7 /path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py --no_cookies update myapp
```

> --no_cookies

Do not store the administrator sign-in credentials as a cookie; prompt for a password every time.
This flag will bring up a prompt for your email address as well.

Comment: Thanks, will try it! 
With golang it's go /path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py --no_cookies update myapp? or can I just use: goapp --no_cookies deploy myapp

Comment: Flag provided but not defined?